# Shiny sliderinput powers of 2

Tags: r, shiny, slider

Is it possible to create a R Shiny sliderInput that only accepts powers of 2? I see custom formatting [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html), but it's not clear how to add a superscript or constrain the slider otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the linked answer from @neilfws is spot on. I've adapted it below for your needs (must view in browser to allow the JS to run):

```
library("shiny")

# expSlider javascript function
JS.expify <-
  "
// function to exponentiate a sliderInput
function expSlider (sliderId, sci = false) {
  $('#'+sliderId).data('ionRangeSlider').update({
  'prettify': function (num) { return ('2<sup>'+num+'</sup>'); }
  })
}"

# call expSlider for each relevant sliderInput
JS.onload <-
"
// execute upon document loading
$(document).ready(function() {
// wait a few ms to allow other scripts to execute
setTimeout(function() {
// include call for each slider
expSlider('exp_slider', sci = true)
}, 5)})
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JS.expify))),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JS.onload))),

  sliderInput("exp_slider", "Powers of 2 Slider:",
              min = -5, max = 10, value = 1, step = 1),

  br(),

  textOutput("selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$selection <- reactive({
    paste0("Selected power: ", input$exp_slider, "     Value = ", 2^input$exp_slider)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]